# how to enable Show-Paren mode only for *.el files

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I enable Show-Paren mode only for *.el files?

I have tried

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook '(lambda()
                                   (show-paren-mode 1)
                                   ))
```

But it still enables Show-Paren mode for all the cases. Even in `*scratch*` buffer I have Show-Paren mode enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already said, `show-paren-mode` is a global minor mode. That said, one might be able to run it only on some buffer with something like:

```
(show-paren-mode)                       ;; activate the needed timer
(setq show-paren-mode ())                ;; The timer will do nothing if this is nil

(defun show-paren-local-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (make-local-variable 'show-paren-mode) ;; The value of shom-paren-mode will be local to this buffer.
  (setq show-paren-mode t))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'show-paren-local-mode)
```

It's untested, it might not work. Looking at the doc in might work, but looking at the code it might work. This might work only with some version of show-paren-mode.

Answer (score 4):

`show-paren-mode` is a global minor-mode.  It means exactly how it sounds.
This is very much by design, as most people (myself included) find this
minor-mode helpful across all buffers.  Why do you want to disable it for any
file?

from the documentation

> Show Paren mode is a global minor mode.  When enabled, any
>   matching parenthesis is highlighted in `show-paren-style' after`
>   show-paren-delay' seconds of Emacs idle time.

Comment: Show Paren mode is absolutely indispensable working with Lisp. But it is not much necessary working with simple text, therefore I dont want additional distraction of something highlighting when working with usual text.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. However, you should consider the fact that the `*scratch*` buffer's major mode is `lisp-interaction-mode` which derives from `emacs-lisp-mode` (which is mostly irrelevant) and the mode's definition:

```
(define-minor-mode show-paren-mode
  "Toggle visualization of matching parens (Show Paren mode).
With a prefix argument ARG, enable Show Paren mode if ARG is
positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
the mode if ARG is omitted or nil.

Show Paren mode is a global minor mode.  When enabled, any
matching parenthesis is highlighted in `show-paren-style' after
`show-paren-delay' seconds of Emacs idle time."
  :global t :group 'paren-showing
...)
```

`:global t` is the key thing here - the mode is global and is enabled in all buffers regardless of their major mode.

Comment: But why the same problem occurs for Text mode?

Comment: It's a global minor-mode, in normal operation, it's activated everywhere or nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```lisp
(setq-default show-paren-data-function #'ignore)
(show-paren-mode)
```

to formally enable the mode but keeping it quiet. And then something like

```lisp
(defun set-up-emacs-lisp-mode ()
  (setq-local show-paren-data-function #'show-paren--default))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'set-up-emacs-lisp-mode)
```

to enable it in Emacs Lisp buffers. I've not tested this set-up, only the opposite (usually enabled, disabled just in Text Mode).

I used to use `(setq-local show-paren-mode nil)` but this makes Emacs highlight the braces in Ido promps, so I prefer `(setq-default show-paren-data-function #'ignore)`.